# Schröder–Bernstein theorem for finite sets

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I want to prove Schröder–Bernstein theorem for 2 finite sets $A, B$ of the same cardinal. I do it with induction on the cardinal number of $A, B$. In the inducative step, I write:

Let $A, B$ sets such that $|A|=|B|=n+1$ for some $n\in\omega$. Here, I want to use the the inducative assumption for the sets $A-\{a\}, B-\{b\}$ for some $a\in A, b\in B$. For choosing the above $a,b$, do I need to use the axiom of choice?

Comment: What could be meant by "the Schröder-Bernstein theorem for 2 finite sets $A,B$ of the same cardinal"? The **conclusion** of the Schröder-Bernstein theorem is that the two sets have the same cardinal, so if you start by considering only sets of the same cardinal then there's nothing to prove.

Comment: No, you don't need choice to choose from a non-empty set. Even if the set is infinite. Choice is needed when *infinitely many choices* needs to be made. When one or two, or five, are needed, then you are not appealing to the axiom of choice at all.

Comment: @AsafKaragila But the induction's step is 'computed' $א_0$ times.

Comment: But at each given step it is only computed finitely many times.